# How to use _timestamp in a scripted update

Tags: elasticsearch, timestamp, updates

I was trying to come up with an elegant answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28526717/conditional-upsert-using-elasticsearch) and ran into an unexpected problem. The basic idea is to update a document based on its current timestamp. Seems straightforward enough, but I seem to be missing something. At the bottom of the [Update API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html) page, the ES docs say:

> It also allows to update the ttl of a document using ctx._ttl and timestamp using ctx._timestamp. Note that if the timestamp is not updated and not extracted from the _source it will be set to the update date.

The ES documentation is often enigmatic at best, especially when it comes to scripting, but I took this to mean that I could use the `_timestamp` field in an update script.

So I set up a simple index with a timestamp:

```
PUT /test_index
{
   "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 1,
      "number_of_replicas": 0
   },
   "mappings": {
      "doc": {
         "_timestamp": {
            "enabled": true,
            "store": true,
            "path": "doc_date",
            "format" : "YYYY-MM-dd"
         },
         "properties": {
            "doc_date": {
               "type": "date",
                "format" : "YYYY-MM-dd"
            },
            "doc_text": {
               "type": "string"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

and added some docs:

```
POST /test_index/_bulk
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc","_id":1}}
{"doc_text":"doc1", "doc_date":"2015-2-5"}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc","_id":2}}
{"doc_text":"doc2", "doc_date":"2015-2-10"}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc","_id":3}}
{"doc_text":"doc3", "doc_date":"2015-2-15"}
```

If I query for the first doc, I get back what I expect:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
           "doc_text": "doc1"
        }
    }, 
    "fields": [
       "_timestamp",
       "_source"
    ]
}
...
{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 1.4054651,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1.4054651,
            "_source": {
               "doc_text": "doc1",
               "doc_date": "2015-2-5"
            },
            "fields": {
               "_timestamp": 1423094400000
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

So far so good. Now I want to conditionally update the first doc, based on its timestamp. First I tried this, and got an error:

```
POST /test_index/doc/1/_update
{
   "script": "if(ctx._timestamp < new_ts){ctx._source.doc_date=new_date;ctx._source.doc_text=new_text}",
   "params": {
      "new_ts": 1423526400000,
      "new_date": "2015-2-10",
      "new_text": "doc1-updated"
   }
}
...
{
   "error": "ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[failed to execute script]; nested: PropertyAccessException[[Error: could not access: _timestamp; in class: java.util.HashMap]\n[Near : {... if(ctx._timestamp < new_ts){ctx._ ....}]\n                ^\n[Line: 1, Column: 4]]; ",
   "status": 400
}
```

Then I tried this:

```
POST /test_index/doc/1/_update
{
   "script": "if(ctx[\"_timestamp\"] < new_ts){ctx._source.doc_date=new_date;ctx._source.doc_text=new_text}",
   "params": {
      "new_ts": 1423526400000,
      "new_date": "2015-2-10",
      "new_text": "doc1-updated"
   }
}
...
{
   "_index": "test_index",
   "_type": "doc",
   "_id": "1",
   "_version": 2
}
```

I didn't get an error, but the update didn't happen:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
           "doc_text": "doc1"
        }
    }, 
    "fields": [
       "_timestamp",
       "_source"
    ]
}
...
{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 1.287682,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1.287682,
            "_source": {
               "doc_text": "doc1",
               "doc_date": "2015-2-5"
            },
            "fields": {
               "_timestamp": 1423094400000
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Just out of curiosity, I inverted the conditional:

```
POST /test_index/doc/1/_update
{
   "script": "if(ctx[\"_timestamp\"] > new_ts){ctx._source.doc_date=new_date;ctx._source.doc_text=new_text}",
   "params": {
      "new_ts": 1423526400000,
      "new_date": "2015-2-10",
      "new_text": "doc1-updated"
   }
}
```

with the same result: no update.

Okay, so as a sanity check I tried to set the timestamp, and got an error:

```
POST /test_index/doc/1/_update
{
   "script": "ctx._source.doc_date=new_date;ctx._source.doc_text=new_text;ctx._timestamp=new_ts",
   "params": {
      "new_ts": 1423526400000,
      "new_date": "2015-2-10",
      "new_text": "doc1-updated"
   }
}
...
{
   "error": "ClassCastException[java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.String]",
   "status": 500
}
```

I also tried it with `"ctx[\"_timestamp\"]=new_ts;"`, and got the same error.

So it seems that the `_timestamp` field is not available to the script, even though the documentation says it is. What am I doing wrong?

I also tried updating without the conditional or updating the timestamp, and it worked as expected.

I used Elasticsearch version 1.3.4 (with dynamic scripting enabled, obviously), running on an Ubuntu 12 VM.

Here is the code I used to set this up:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/ca2b3c6b84572e5f87d57d22f8c38252fa4ee216